# How do I know if my WordPress page was made with Bootstrap?

Tags: css, wordpress, web, responsiveness

I'm trying to figure out whether it would pay off to use Bootstrap on my existing Wordpress site and while researching it, I came up with the idea that the template I'm using might actually already be using Bootstrap.

I can't see any signs of Bootstrap in my *functions.php* file or through the FTP, but the template is using classes like these: ".col-md-4", ".col-sm-4". Is that because it was created with Bootstrap or is it just a convention?

Sorry if this is complete nonsense.

Comment: There are many ways, but the simplest is to check using [devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools), inspect elements and search for bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 1):

That's a classic bootstrap class.

You shouldn't check the PHP files but the css ones or javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a sign.

You can check more bootstrap classes Like `container, row, and ...`

And for being sure you can check **asset** files like **CSS** and **JS** files, if you found **bootstrap css** and **js** files you may be sure of using bootstrap in your template.

You can open asset files it may wrote the bootstrap version in it even.

Comment: There's nothing like bootstrap files in my template's asset folders (and nowhere else, either, as far as I can tell). Am I right in thinking that this shouldn't matter, because if I add bootstrap now, my template will already include bootstrap classes and that will make things easier for me?